# Парсинг email на Python

Tags: python

Добрый день!
Читаю почту с помощью

```
box = poplib.POP3(server, port)
OpenMailbox()
...
(resp, lines, octets) = box.retr(msgnum)
```

далее парсю содержимое с помощью

```
msgtext = "\n".join(lines) + "\n\n"
message = email.message_from_string(msgtext)
```

иногда в message["subject"]
попадаются такое содержимое

```
 =?UTF-8?B?0KHQsdC10YDQsdCw0L3QuiDQntC90LvQsNC50L0uINCe0LTQvdC+0YDQsNC3?=
 =?UTF-8?B?0L7QstGL0Lkg0L/QsNGA0L7Qu9GMINC00LvRjyDQstGF0L7QtNCwIDE2Mzg=?= 
 =?UTF-8?B?Nw==?=
```

Бывает так же =?UTF-8?Q? и другие.
Могу в ручную перекодировать такие заголовки с помощью

```
quopri.decodestring(mystr)
base64.b64decode(mystr)
```

соответственно, но для этого нужно вручную выделять строки, определять наличие проблемы и делать перекодировку для subject, (а так же иногда для полей from, to).
Может быть кто-то подскажет более простой способ чтения почты, решающий проблемы с различными кодировками в письмах?